# Issues with TabLayout getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My application is working fine when I use `getChildFragmentManager()` but unfortunately, it will only work with API 17 and above. Now when I switch it over to `getFragmentManager()`, everything works fine except for one thing. Whenever I load my tablayout in horizontal view, both pages are empty and swiping is sluggish. Vertically it is fine and they won't be empty if I first load them vertically and then switch to horizontally, because I'm using a saved instance. I have no idea what is causing this. All I know is that as soon as I switch the code above around, it happens. Let me know what is required to find the issue and I will gladly post it. I am using the support-v13 library's FragmentPagerAdapter. I am doing this so I don't have to use support-v4's way of creating fragments. I do import the ViewPager from v4 in my tablayout fragment.

Edit:

Okay when the tablayout is created for the first time, it works fine. When called again it will be blank and sluggish. It had nothing to do with orientation.

Edit:

Tablayout code **Keep in mind that this code is functional. But when I change getChildFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager() it gets sluggish and only works on first oncreate**:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 2;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TAB1";
            case 1:
                return "TAB2";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code.